# Rails image_path/url helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an image in **app/assets/images/portfolio/01-example.jpg**

I'm not entirely sure on how to use the `image_url` or `image_path` helpers to display this image in the view.

Is it `<%= image_path('01-example.jpg') %>`? If anyone could correct me with the correct syntax, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to display it in an image tag, ie is your view html?

Then it's

<%= image_tag('portfolio/01-example.jpg') %>